# Adding custom search engine to Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using Thunderbird 52.5.0 (64-bit).

So I am following https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-search-engine-open-search to add a custom search engine to Thunderbird. (I want to add DDG as instructed at https://duck.co/help/desktop/thunderbird but for now I am following the support article.)

This is the google.xml:

```
$ cat ~/.thunderbird/m422kcn9.default/searchplugins/google.xml
<SearchPlugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
<ShortName>Google</ShortName>
<Description>Google Search</Description>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<Image width="16" height="16">https://google.com/favicon.ico</Image>
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" method="GET" template="http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&amp;hl={moz:locale}&amp;q={searchTerms}"/>
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://www.google.com/search">
  <Param name="q" value="{searchTerms}"/>
  <Param name="ie" value="utf-8"/>
  <Param name="oe" value="utf-8"/>
  <Param name="aq" value="t"/>
</Url>
<SearchForm>http://www.google.com</SearchForm>
</SearchPlugin>
```

But I still can't see Google search engine in Preferences -> General -> Default Search Engine list. Am I missing something?

Any pointers will be really helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody on Mozilla Support Forum answered this question. I'm reproducing the solution here just in case anybody winds up here.

1. Create a `searchplugins` directory in the Thunderbird profile directory, and copy into it the desired xml files such as ddg.xml, google.xml etc.
2. When you launch TB, the added search engines are not visible in Options, as expected.
3. Close TB and rename `search.json.mozlz4` in the profile folder to `search.json.mozlz4.OLD`; a new `search.json.mozlz4` is created when TB is launched, and now the added search engines are available in Options.

Comment: As of March 2018, this is the correct answer. The key is to remove/rename search.json.mozlz4 at which point on restart, Thunderbird will recreate it with the search engines you have in the searchplugins directory.

Comment: As of September 2018 (on TB 60.0), this no longer works. Renaming (or removing) the `search.json.mozlz4` file only creates the same file anew, it doesn't seem to care about the `searchplugins` folder at all. Even manually editing the file to include the `ShortName` of the desired search engine has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get both `Google` and `DuckDuckGo` as search engines in your thunderbird, you need to follow the below steps.

**Adding Google as search engine**

- Open this link in web browser and download the [Google search
  plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/google-search-for-thunderbi/) for thunderbird.
- Open thunderbird and click on [image] and click to **Add-ons**. In the Add-on window, click on the [image] icon and select ***Install Add-on from file.***
- Choose the file which you downloaded with the web browser and install
  the Add-on and restart your thunderbird.

The above steps would create a directory directory structure like `extensions/gsearch@standard8.plus.com/` and pu the file `google.xml` in it inside your thunderbird profile directory.

You can see that the `searchplugins` directory contains the `google.xml` file. This file let you use Google as search engine in thunderbird.

Now if you go to [image] **> Preference > General > Default Search Engine**

You can see that Google is listed there.

**Adding DuckDuckGo as search engine**.

- Open this [link](https://duckduckgo.com/opensearch.xml) in any web browser and save the file inside
  `searchplugins` directory. The file name can be anything, but the
  extension should be `.xml`.

The full file path to save the `.xml` file is (Just in case if you have confusion)

```
/home/<username>/.thunderbird/<profilename>/extensions/gsearch@standard8.plus.com/searchplugins/opensearch.xml
```

- Then restart thunderbird.

Now you will get `DuckDuckGo` as search engine in search engine list in the thunderbird preference general
   tab.

Comment: Thanks for the addon suggestion. But I really don't want to install yet another addon for the problem which has a direct knowledge base page https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-search-engine-open-search

Comment: hmm i thought so. i have already tried the mothod you tried, before installing the addon and failed. the xml file from the plugin is different from which we get from the link. i think that is the problem.